Spurious Edits followed by rollbacks
Is something happening with a particular user apparently clobbering questions and answers for no reason? I see a bunch of edits by one person that seem nonsensical then immediately rolled back by someone else.

Yup. One user went on a defacement binge of posts by another user this AM. (All the edits were at the top of front page when I visited this morning. There were probably like five to ten of them.) It looks like yet another user is rolling them back. Regardless of what anyone may think of the posts themselves, I didn't think this kind of personal targeting should be allowed. Hopefully the mods will take some action.

I'm the roll-back-er, I understood that to be the correct course of action in this case; I hope that was appropriate. Separately, I have flagged several times for moderator attention (and a mod has reverted at least one of the changes).

And their vandalism occurs on meta, too (I've reverted one and left the other as clear evidence).

Seems strange: To roll back without other punitive action. Is that policy?

Ok, so they had a reason. It just wasn't a good reason, ha ha

This was seemingly an act of self-justice out of revenge for a single edit in the other direction which wasn't taken well. For future reference: please try to flag every butchered post. Makes it easier for us to manage the situation.
The user was contacted and we made clear that this kind of behaviour will not be tolerated here.
Quite childish if you ask me.

I still reiterate my question in comment above: Whats the policy in such cases?

@Rushi There is no explicit policy. It wasn't just rolled back, there have been flags raised and since it was the first time the user showed inappropriate behaviour, I let it slip with a warning.

@PhilipKlöcking Respectfully, this is a user with over 1000 rep who chose to target a specific other user in a way they cannot have possibly assumed was appropriate. If that's not worthy of at least a short term ban, I'm not sure what is.

@NoahSchweber Be assured I did not make this call without considering it, yet we showed so much lenience towards others over the years that I would have considered it inconsistent. Generally, I agree with your sentiment, just wanted to err on the right side if you know what I mean
